# How to identify unused tables from the oracle database

Tags: oracle

I have a production database with 1500 tables. Want to cleanup few tables that are created for testing purpose. Is there any process to identify unused tables.

Note: Auditing is not enabled in the database

Answer (score 1):

You need to take snapshots of `v$segment_statistics` on a regular basis and then compare the data over time.

Something like:

```
create table usage_statistics
(  
   as_of timestamp,
   table_name  varchar(30), 
   table_owner varchar(30),
   num_logical_reads number, 
   num_physical_reads number, 
   num_full_scans
);
```

Then create e.g. a `cron` or `dbms_scheduler` job to run the following

```
insert into usage_statistics (as_of, table_name, table_owner, num_logical_reads, num_physical_reads, num_full_scans)
select current_timestamp, 
       object_name,
       owner,
       sum(case when statistic_name = 'logical reads' then value end),
       sum(case when statistic_name = 'physical reads' then value end),
       sum(case when statistic_name = 'segment scans' then value end),
from v$segment_statistics
where owner in ('USER_NAME_1', 'USER_NAME_2')
 and object_type = 'TABLE'
group by object_type, object_name
order by object_type, object_name;
```

Of course you will need to adjust the names of the owners you want to monitor.

The above statement only checks for three statistics. Use the view [V$SEGSTAT_NAME](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-3381E4A9-D83C-48F7-9084-D7360839CE98.htm#REFRN30222) to see a list of all available statistic names in `v$segment_statistics`

Then after a while you can compare the changes in the reads for each table.

Comment: Thanks for update

Answer (score 0):

I started from this:

```
select table_name, last_analyzed
  from user_tables
 order by last_analyzed desc;

select table_name, last_analyzed
  from all_tables
 order by last_analyzed desc;
```

I ask programmers and I droped the oldest tables.

Comment: If you routinely gather stats on the schema, the "last analyzed" date won't tell you anything about table usage patterns.